# What could cause a sub-pixel defect that is only visible under certain conditions?

Tags: lcd, pixels

An interesting but annoying pixel fault has appeared on the display of my laptop. At first glance it looked like a Stuck Pixel defect (one or two red, one blue and one green sub-pixel) but then I notices that it is only visible under certain conditions. Namely, when the column of the screen directly below it is very bright and the spot itself is surrounded by dark colors. That is the case for example when using a browser in incognito mode or using a dark theme in general. Interestingly enough it is completely invisible when the screen is completely white or completely black and moste other times, too. To illustrate that a little I'v attached a video in which I move a dark colored window below the faulty sub-pixels. You can see that its appearance only seems to be affected by the narrow column of the screen directly below it and that it only shows when that area is showing a very bright color. In fact, the more of that vertical area is bright, the more it is visible (as can be seen at the end of the video when I move the black window vertically). So I suppose it's probably not the classic stuck sub-pixel because that would not change depending on other parts of the screen, right? It's also there when booting into another OS. Does anyone have an idea what kind of issue could be causing this (graphics hardware, faulty cable, etc.) and whether it could be fixed?

[image: Picture of the the red, green and blue 'stuck' sub-pixels]

[Video of the phenomenon on vimeo.com](https://vimeo.com/515321732)

Comment: First you should determine whether this is a **video RAM** fault, or a fault of the display processor. Can you run a comprehensive RAM memory check? I'm assuming that video RAM is mapped from general-purpose RAM.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question regarding display technology and possible failure modes. I vote to keep it open.

Comment: You say it's bright when the column below it is bright. So how about a faulty row select connection on these cells? So they are always connected to the column lines even when other rows are being addressed.

Comment: video RAM: The graphics hardware is an Intel UHD Graphics 620. Could you maybe recommend testing software for this purpose? I don't know what exactly has to be tested and what the results should show. @user253751 Sounds interesting, although I have to admit that I don't have the expertise to evaluate that appropriately. Do you have an idea on how I could investigate on this further?

Comment: @Arminius Your video RAM is almost certainly fine. I've never heard of dead pixels caused by video RAM. Does it move when you change the resolution? If so, it's a video RAM problem. If not, it's a display problem.

Comment: Indeed, I tried switching the resolution. It stayed where it was.

Answer (score 1):

The charge layer trapped suffers from crosstalk , or leakage like memory test failures that depend on adjacent word patterns .  Run Dead pixel test tor windows DPT.exe to fix. It’s a defect that can often be corrected by cycling patterns around the pixel zone rapidly.
LCD’s are like dynamic RAM that need to refreshed.

Comment: I have already tried DPT with no luck so far. Then again I read somewhere that it could take several hours to show some effect. I will now try to cycle the lower half of the screen from black to white at 100 ms for some time. That will switch between "the issu is 100% visible" and "the issue is not visible at all".

Comment: It might take days to burn off the contamination or never.  But just move the small square over the pixels. Mine is 250 ms minimum but that's just the screensaver (autocycle). the dead area goes faster

Comment: Ok, I'll try it again and leave it at least over night next time.

Comment: Also, I think I had some faulty pixel on another laptop some years ago which just disappeared by itself some day, as suddenly as it first appeared.

Comment: No change after ~ 14 h of DPT's Exerciser. - Correction: It was UDPixel's "Undead Pixel".

Comment: Just wanted to add that I think that it might not be an issue with the display itself (but maybe with the display cable) because it is not visible at all for example when the screen is all black, all white or any other solid color. A "normal" stuck (sub-)pixel should be visible at least in some solid colors. Also: Is it possible to move the question to SU SA where it is not deemed to be OT, maybe? :)

Comment: What cable type and display? It’s a laptop